# My website displays weird in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have this website: http://discovrd.com/

If you're viewing that navigation bar of that website in Chrome or Firefox, it displays correctly, but when I view it in IE 8 or other IE browsers, it totally messes everything up.
I'm not a CSS guru, so I don't know how to solve this one.

Kindly help me how to fix this one. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks! :)

Comment: Start reducing things down. Strip away the unnecessary CSS and see where exactly the problem lies. *Then* post about it, once we actually have something to look at.

Comment: Day by day, @Mitch, one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Can't say for sure exactly, but for starters you have a random opened `ul` after the conservative link; F12 tools in IE8 shows that menu's `li` children actually are not.

Validate your markup and styles. Use F12 tools to debug in IE. :)

Comment: Thanks for being so polite in answering my question. :) I just noticed that IE are so sensitive when it comes to unclosed tags. And yes you are correct about what you wrote. That gave me a good start.